# Convert existing WebSocket implementation into Reactive WebSocket in Android Java

Tags: android, websocket, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I am using OKHttpClient with WebSockets in Android.
I want to convert it into reactive programming.
How to achieve this.
For now i am doing this for WebSocket Connection.

```
    // OkHttp Client
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

    // WebSocket Object
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
    mWebSocket = httpClient.newWebSocket(request, new WebSocketListener() {
        // Override methods - OnOpen, OnMessage, OnClosing, OnFailure
    }

    // Then Calling this to make websocket request
    mWebSocket.send(message);
```

I have found this library to use Reactive WebSocket
https://github.com/jacek-marchwicki/JavaWebsocketClient

But there is no Callback Listener as 'WebSocketListener' so i can handle the messages.

Any help would be appreciated in this direction. Thanks

Comment: Any update on how to do this? I'm having the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/67782867/11110509

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE I use this library and it did the work. https://github.com/dhhAndroid/RxWebSocket

Answer (score 0):

There is retrofit inspired websocket client by Tinder
https://github.com/Tinder/Scarlet

Here apart from sending and receiving regular messages, you can also create a reactive stream to receive **Websocket.Event** and filter incoming events like *onOpen, onMessage, onFailed* etc.

Below is an example on how to do that. Goto the link provided above for detailed example

```
//Service declaration similar to retrofit
interface MyWebsocketService{
    @Receive
    Flowable<WebSocket.Event> observeWebSocketEvent();
}

Scarlet scarletInstance = new Scarlet.Builder()
    .webSocketFactory(OkHttpClientUtils.newWebSocketFactory(okhttpClient,"websocket-server-url")
    .addStreamAdapterFactory(new RxJava2StreamAdapterFactory())
    .build();

MyWebsocketService myWebsocketService = scarletInstance.create<MyWebsocketService>();

myWebsocketService.observeWebsocketEvent()
                  .subscribe(event -> {
                      if(event instanceof Websocket.Event.OnConnectionOpened){
                         //do something here
                      }else if(event instanceof Websocket.Event.OnConnectionClosed){
                        //do something here
                      }
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using OkHttp at all, but short answer is put [PublishSubject](https://medium.com/p/ef9183b5e87e) in your OnMessage method. Subject will provide this message to your subscriber and you could also create a chain before subscription.

```
// OkHttp Client
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

// Creating a Subject
// You can use it as Observer or Subscriber
PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();

// WebSocket Object
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
mWebSocket = httpClient.newWebSocket(request, new WebSocketListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(String text, ...) {
        subject.onNext(text);
    }
}

// I hope that is an queue option
mWebSocket.send(message);

// Do what you want with your message
Disposable subscription = subject.flatMap(...)
                                 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                 .subscribe(...);
```

In sum, it's complicated question because you should handle connection errors, data pressure, config changes and be lifecycle-aware, but it also relevant for non-reactive way (e.g callback-hell), so PublishSubject is a start point.