# RxJava + Websocket - How to add Observable to Websocket listener?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, okhttp, android-mvvm

I have a `ViewModel` that is observing a RxJava `Observable` in my `MainRepo` class. I am trying to get my `WebsocketListener` in the `MainRepo` class to emit events, but I'm unsure how to do so.

**MainRepo class:**

```
private WebSocket ws;

public void createWsConnection() {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(Constants.WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT)
                .addHeader(Constants.WEBSOCKET_HEADERS_KEY, Constants.USER_ID)
                .build();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient
                .Builder()
                .pingInterval(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        this.ws = client.newWebSocket(request, webSocketListener);
    }
```

This is where I'm confused. I don't know how I would use the websocket with the RxJava observable.

```
public Observable<String> createListener(){
        return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) {
                 //I don't know what to put here in order to emit messages
                 //back to my ViewModel class using the websocket listener
            }
        });
    }
```

**The websocket listener:**

```
 private WebSocketListener webSocketListener = new WebSocketListener() {

        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
            Timber.d("Ws connection opened...", response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onClosing(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, int code, @NotNull String reason) {
            Timber.d("Ws connection closing...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onClosed(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, int code, @NotNull String reason) {
            Timber.d("Ws connection closed...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, @NotNull String text) {
            Timber.d("Ws incoming message.");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, @NotNull Throwable t, Response response) {
            Timber.e(t, "Ws connection failure.", response.toString());

        }
    };
```

**A function in the ViewModel class that is observing the Observable in my MainRepo class:**

```
public void connectToWs(){
        mainRepo.createListener()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                Timber.d("Subscribed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(@NonNull String s) {
                Timber.d("Message: " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                Timber.e(e, "Something went wrong.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Timber.d("On complete.");
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [PublishSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/subjects/PublishSubject.html) and change your `createListener` method to return it:

```java
private PublishSubject<String> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create<String>();

public Observable<String> createListener(){
    return publishSubject;
}
```

PublishSubject is an Observable so notice that you don't need to change your method signature, but I'd suggest you to rename the method name to something like `observeMessages`.

Then in your websocket listener you can emit the messages to the PublishSubject with [onNext](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/subjects/PublishSubject.html#onNext-T-) method. You should also call [onComplete](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/subjects/PublishSubject.html#onComplete--) in the onClosed method and [onError](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/subjects/PublishSubject.html#onError-java.lang.Throwable-) in the onFailure method:

```java
 private WebSocketListener webSocketListener = new WebSocketListener() {

        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
            Timber.d("Ws connection opened...", response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onClosing(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, int code, @NotNull String reason) {
            Timber.d("Ws connection closing...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onClosed(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, int code, @NotNull String reason) {
            Timber.d("Ws connection closed...");

            publishSubject.onComplete();
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, @NotNull String text) {
            Timber.d("Ws incoming message.");

            publishSubject.onNext(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, @NotNull Throwable t, Response response) {
            Timber.e(t, "Ws connection failure.", response.toString());

            publishSubject.onError(t);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

PublishSubject is the solution like Gustavo posted. But `createListener()`  looks strange and i just want to show how i do it.

I'm not using OkHttp, but i do exactly same things with [nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client). It's just another websocket client.

In my scenario i do a lot of reactive stuff before, but the socket flow is:

- connect to socket
- register `OnTextMessage` listener - it should provides message to me
- send messages to get permament answers from socket

Somewhere in `OnCreate / OnCreateView`:

```
// Creating socket with credentials
WebSocketFactory factory = new WebSocketFactory();

try {
    socket = factory.createSocket("wss://ws.example.com", 3000);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Create a subject
PublishSubject<String> subject = PublishSubject.create();
```

I have done some `HTTP/GET` work before and save results in `List<String> symbols` - it also reactive way. After this i call `subscribeToSymbols` method which does a whole socket stuff:

```
public static Single<WebSocket> subscribeToSymbols(WebSocket socket,
                                                   PublishSubject<String> subject,
                                                   List<StockHttpGetData> symbols) {
    // connect -> register onTextMessage callback -> sendMessages to Socket
    return Single.fromCallable(socket::connect)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(s -> s.addListener(new WebSocketAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String text) {
                    subject.onNext(text);
                }
            }))
            .doAfterSuccess(s -> symbols.forEach(httpData -> sendMessageToSubscribe(s, httpData)));
}
```

You are not interested in what `subscribeToSymbols` returns. The key point that `subject.onNext(text)` provides received message from socket to you if you subscribed to this subject.

Finally, subscribe to subject what you've created before and do what you want with message:

```
subject.flatMap(t -> Observable.just(new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(TreeSet.class, new SocketMessageDeserializer())
            .create()
            .fromJson(t, TreeSet.class)))
       .filter(treeSet -> !treeSet.isEmpty())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .doOnNext(StocksRepository.getInstance()::printSocketMessage)
       .subscribe(adapter::setStocksChanged, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

The fact that it's complicated question because you should also handle connection errors, data pressure, config changes and be lifecycle-aware, but it also relevant for non-reactive way (e.g callback-hell), so PublishSubject is a start point.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [PublishSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/subjects/PublishSubject.html), seems like it was created for cases like yours.

Comment: My problem is I don't know how to get the messages in the websocket listener to send messages back with the ```subscribe(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<String> emitter```. if you can post example that would be great.